# Langmuir parameters for fixed bed continous column

Tags: equilibrium, computational-chemistry, adsorption

I have prepared a model of fixed bed adsorption column in MATLAB. I have to insert Langmuir parameter value there, so how can I calculate them in case of continuous fixed bed column. I have calculated them in previous batch study. How to calculate them for continuous column, what data should I get?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Could you edit your question to add more info?